# Filemaker Pro - Using Script to populate report layout

Tags: report, filemaker

I have a problem where I have a list of fields from a table (not static, can be modified by user), and I need to generate a report using these user selected fields. The report can show all the rows, no need for aggregation or filtering.

I thought I could create a report layout then using a filemaker script to populate it but can't seem to find the right commands, can someone let me know how I could achieve this?

I'm using filemaker pro 18 advanced

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. So a user selects which fields they want to show on the report, and then you want to show those fields in a list? Are you reporting on _all_ records in the table or only certain ones that match search criteria? Does your report need to show any aggregate data? Yes you'll use a script, but it's impossible to explain the "how" if we don't know the "what".

Comment: Yes that's correct, the report columns will be dynamic based on user selection. I just need to display all the rows, no need to show aggregate data.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Since you want a dynamic report, then I recommend you look up a technique called "Virtual List" for rendering the data.

Here's an example script that iterates over a found set of records and builds the virtual list data in a variable (it doesn't show how to render it though):

```
# Field names and delimiter
Set Variable [ $delim ; Value: Char(9) // tab character ] 
# Set these dynamically with a script parameter
Set Variable [ $fields ; Value: List ( "Contacts::nameFirst" ; "Contacts::nameCompany" ; "Contacts::nameLast" ) ] 
Set Variable [ $fieldCount ; Value: ValueCount ( $fields ) ] 

Go to Layout [ “Contacts” (Contacts) ; Animation: None ]
Show All Records
Go to Record/Request/Page [ First ]

# Loop over all the records and append a row in the $data variable for each
Set Variable [ $data ; Value: "" ] 
Loop
    # Get the delimited field values
    Set Variable [ $i ; Value: 0 ] 
    Set Variable [ $row ; Value: "" ] 
    Loop
        Exit Loop If [ Let ( $i = $i + 1 ; $i > $fieldCount ) ] 
        Set Variable [ $value ; Value: GetField ( GetValue ( $fields ; $i ) ) ] 
        Insert Calculated Result [ Target: $row ; If ( $i > 1 ; $delim ) & $value ] 
    End Loop
    enter code here
    # Append the new row of data to the list variable
    Insert Calculated Result [ Target: $data ; If ( Get ( RecordNumber ) > 1 ; ¶ ) & $row ] 
    Go to Record/Request/Page [ Next ; Exit after last: On ]
End Loop

# Save to a global variable to show in a virtual list layout
Set Variable [ $$DATA ; Value: $data ] 

Exit Script [ Text Result:    ]
```

*please note* this code is just one of many possible formats the virtual list can take. A lot of people, myself included, prefer to use JSON objects or arrays for each row of the list since it automatically handle field values with carriage returns. This is sort of the old-fashioned way. Kevin Frank at FileMaker Hacks has some good recent articles about virtual list techniques if you're interested.

PS, another great technique for rendering table data dynamically is to collect the data in a JSON array and render it in a webviewer with https://datatables.net/

Comment: This is indeed great, but my problem here is I don't know what will the resulting columns be, from reading this and checking the example, they all came with pre-defined fields in the report layout. What I needed is for the script to populate the report layout with the columns. Maybe I'm missing something, but can this method achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

I did something like this for the oncology department of UM om 1980 or so using 4th Dimension and a new plug in that used one line of code to create a web browser with all the functions that a doctor might want. The data was placed inside a variable as it was sent/returned and 4D could use a variable in the report to display the data.

FileMaker does not have this ability built in as 4D did so you will have to do it yourself.JSON is the most likely tool that I am familiar with. YouTube has many videos on JSON.

You have two classes of variables for your report: Column headers and column data to display. Fortunately Filemaker is quite good and very easy to design. Just make a typical report and replace the text/header or field names with a JSON variable or any. $ColumnName = JSON variable.

Create a JSON calculated field in the database. In that calculated field set the JSON variable and this can be used for all of the columns.

This is the essence of the idea with the final result to be determined by you. What you are asking for is not easy and would require serious work by a skilled JSON scripter.